# Is it possible to customize RichTextBox.DetectUrls behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

RichTextBox will highlight standard http urls and allow me to catch when someone clicks on this link. But the current project I'm working on requires me to make links with a custom url scheme so instead of http://foo.bat I have myapp://some.host/params.

Is it possible to customize the way RichTextBox's DetectUrls does it's thing?

**Update**: This is in context of a WinForms app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! it's possible. Check out [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx) in codeproject.

Comment: Very good tip thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work with mono, but I'd take it for now since about 90% of my users are on windows.